# How to change search limit of three characters in osclass

Tags: php, search, limit, osclass

I am using osclass version 3.8 with theme zara, in my website when i am searching for 4 characters like "neet" than it's showing perfect result but whenever i am trying to search word less than three characters as "iit" than it's showing no match.

**I want to change this three character search limit of osclass to 1.**

Answer (score 0):

modify mysql config file (minimum and maximum):

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
```

and

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
```